# Weblogic server 32-bit on 64 bit linux box

Tags: linux, weblogic-10.x, jdk6

I have Weblogic server setup 32-bit(wls1033_linux32.bin) and jdk6 64-bit(jdk-6u24-linux-x64.bin).... can i install and run successfully on a 64-bit Linux machine?
Please give me the break up of what all i need to install WL server on 64-bit linux machine....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Oracle's certification matrix](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs103/103_over/overview.html) - it lists all supported version combinations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wls1034_generic.jar that you should be using for this environment.